# It is possible to create a script for generating new sites on a google analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to create a script (php for example) to generate new sites on a google analytics account.

I need to obtain the ID of the generated site.

¿It is possible to do it? How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All of the Google Analytics APIs are read-only. The only way to create new accounts is manually.

As @jk added below, from the [Google Analytics Management API docs:](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html)

> Google Analytics provides developer access to the configuration data
>   through the Management API, which is a read-only API for account and
>   configuration data.

Comment: are you sure 100% about this?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 `Google Analytics provides developer access to the configuration data through the Management API, which is a read-only API for account and configuration data.` http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html

Comment: I have seen this question asked in other places too - and the answer has always been the GA web interface must be used.